# How combine Unity project as a Library with Android Project Application

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, android-ndk

I have read a lot about this topic, how to integrate Android App with Unity App, and it's seem to be something really strange.

I have check post like this http://www.41post.com/5292/programming/unity-and-android-create-an-unity-app-with-a-custom-layout

which is working fine. But, in this case, the developer after export Unity Project to Android Studio, he start to develop his code inside the project that Unity has created.

This is not the same thing I have to do, I need to export Unity Project, make this a module marked as a Library and be imported for another Android Project.

Making this I have achived compile but in runtime I have different erros, some erros like "Unable to find Main", I have changed gradle and recompile with ndk to recognize .so files but is not working, when I open App it's say something like "Failure to initialize! Your hardware does not support this application, sorry!" and this have no sense because this Unity app has been tested in the same device and works.

Maybe is something that can't be done, and Im just totally lost.

Has someone make this happens?

Thanks,

Regards.